# Line chart (google chart) custom labels

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, google-visualization

Well, I am using a LineChart with Angular 4 and I make sure to change labels according to window size like the following:

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event']) onResize(event) {
  if (event.target['innerWidth'] < 420) {
    this.stockAnalysisService.getOptionsY()['hAxis']['format'] = 'MMM';
  } else if (event.target['innerWidth'] < 760) {
    this.stockAnalysisService.getOptionsY()['hAxis']['format'] = 'MM. yy\'';
  } else { this.stockAnalysisService.getOptionsY()['hAxis']['format'] = 'MMM d, yyyy'; }
this.drawBasic();
}
```

This is just basic Angular syntax to detect resize or window and change the hAxis labels accordingly.

My question is, if I want a custom label where I present months on the labels and the months are presented with values of **DAY OF THE MONTH** and ONLY the first day of the month will have an addition of text to it like the following image:

[image]

**RED**: days of the month (jumps 5 days each time but not relevant)
**BLACK**: first indication of the month (Should not be NOV 10, but NOV 1, not relevant)

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to have one or more labels different from than rest,
will need to use option --> `hAxis.ticks`

this means you will need to build an array of the labels that should be displayed

using object notation, for each tick you can provide
the value of the tick (`v:`)
and the formatted value of the tick (`f:`)

```
{v: dateValue, f: displayValue}
```

the value (`v:`) should be the same type as the x-axis, in this case --> `'date'`
the formatted value (`f:`) should be --> `'string'`

if you don't use object notation, and just provide a date for the tick,
the label will be displayed according to --> `hAxis.format`

so, for the dates that should have the month prefix,
use object notation, for the rest, just provide the date

see following working snippet for an example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart', 'table']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y0');
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2017, 7, 1), 2],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 2), 3],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 4), 1],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 8), 5],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 16), 6],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 20), 7],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 24), 1],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 26), 2],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 27), 3],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 1), 2],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 2), 3],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 4), 9],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 8), 5],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 16), 6],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 20), 7],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 24), 1],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 26), 2],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 27), 3]
  ]);

  var oneDay = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  var dateRange = data.getColumnRange(0);
  var formatMonth = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: 'MMM dd'
  });

  // build ticks
  var ticksX = [];
  for (var i = dateRange.min.getTime(); i <= dateRange.max.getTime(); i = i + oneDay) {
    var rowDate = new Date(i);
    if (rowDate.getDate() === 1) {
      // add first day of month
      ticksX.push({
        v: rowDate,
        f: formatMonth.formatValue(rowDate)
      });
    } else if (((i - dateRange.min.getTime()) % 7) === 0) {
      // add date every seven days
      ticksX.push(rowDate);
    }
  }

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
  chart.draw(data, {
    chartArea: {
      bottom: 36,
      left: 48,
      right: 12,
      top: 12,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%'
    },
    hAxis: {
      format: 'dd',
      ticks: ticksX
    },
    width: 800
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: This is certainly what I need. I was about to use 'ready' event to manipulate existing data. This is better. Thank you.